# CSGO: How to disable "deathcam" from the server level?

Tags: steam, pc, counter-strike-global-offensive

This is not a thread for discussing the justification for / against "deathcam".

I am building dedicated servers for CSGO tournament play (in a 100+ seat LAN setting), and require the settings to disable "deathcam".

The present configuration involves CSGO itself (with esl5v5 config), sourcemod, metamod, and warmod.

I have direct access to the OS level (ssh), as I own the servers themselves (no rental server control panel).

Further I have obtained a full dump of available "cvars", none of which appear to do the trick (*cvarlist log cvarlist.txt*).

While conducting research, I have found several references, none of which work:

- disable in game settings menu

  - irrelevant, as this would have to be done for each user, hard to enforce
- "spec_freeze_time -1"

  - ineffective, deathcam persists
- "sv_disablefreezecam 1"

  - ineffective, deathcam persists
- "mp_fadetoblack 1"

  - ineffective, deathcam persists

Please do consider and advise how this might be accomplished?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: hint: Enable it on game settings, copy settings file elsewhere, disable it, compare differences between two.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you might be running a casual server by default, and then modifying the cvars on the server so it essentially becomes a heavily modified casual server with competitive settings.

Try using the following commands

```
game_mode 1;
game_type 0;
```

This will force the default competitive settings. Follow this with

```
exec gamemode_competitive.cfg
```

And then finally restart with `mp_restartgame 1`, `exec <your league script>`, and restart again.